# array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in

Tags: php

Estou consumindo um Web Service pela primeira vez, criei uma função para percorrer as colunas de uma variável, encontrar o valor que preciso, usando o array_search localizar outro valor numa variável diferente e substituir os nomes o grande problema é que, **as vezes** ao recarregar a página ele me retorna erros em diversas linhas, **algumas vezes nos array_column** outras **no array_search** ou **foreach**:

> array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

na linha:

`$loc =  array_column($local, 'codigo');`

> array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in

nas linhas:

`$cat =  array_column($categoria, 'codigo');`

`$categorizacao = $categoria[$key4]['nome'];` 

`$key3 = array_search($result['local'], $loc);`

e me retornou o erro:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

na linha:

`foreach($resultado as $result){`

eu tentei adicionar varias linhas com is_array, mas com certeza isso não está certo, e o erro ainda acontece, eu gostaria de saber se eu consigo adicionar mais de uma variável no is_array, pra usar somente um, ou uma forma correta para aplicar no meu código, sou iniciante em php, conto com a ajuda de vocês!

```
$retorno_resultados = array();

$colunas =  array_column($equipe, 'codigo'); 

$loc =  array_column($local, 'codigo');

$cat =  array_column($categoria, 'codigo');

foreach((array)$modalidade as $modali){

    if(!is_array($modali)){

        }else{

$mod =  array_column($modalidade, 'codigo');

    }

}

foreach((array)$campeonato as $camp){
    if(!is_array($camp)){

        }else{

            $key4 = array_search($camp['categoria'], $cat);
            $categorizacao = $categoria[$key4]['nome']; // <-- pega o valor

            $key5 = array_search($camp['modalidade'], $mod);
            $modalidadez = $modalidade[$key5]['nome']; // <-- pega o valor

    foreach((array)$resultado as $result){
        if(!is_array($result)){

        }else{

            // pesquisa chave do mandante
            $key1 = array_search($result['mandante'], $colunas);
            $mandante = $equipe[$key1]['nome']; // <-- pega o valor

            // pesquisa chave do visitante
            $key2 = array_search($result['visitante'], $colunas);
            $visitante = $equipe[$key2]['nome']; // <-- pega o valor

            // pesquisa chave do local
            $key3 = array_search($result['local'], $loc);
            $localizacao = $local[$key3]['nome']; // <-- pega o valor

            $data = $result['data'];
            $data = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data));

            $i = 0;
```

**$colunas**

```
 {
"codigo": "26",
"nome": "Xingu SA",
"nomeabreviado": "XINGU",
"url": "xingu-sa",
"telefone": "",
"email": "",
"endereco": "",
"complemento": null,
"bairro": "",
"cidade": "",
"uf": "",
"cep": ""
},
  "Total de registros: 36"
],
```

**$mod**

```
{
"codigo": "256",
"nome": "Xadrez",
"tipo": "6"
},
  "Total de registros: 47"
],
```

**$loc**

```
{
"codigo": "17",
"nome": "Villare SCS",
"modalidade": "16",
"telefone": "",
"email": "",
"endereco": "",
"complemento": null,
"bairro": "",
"cidade": "",
"uf": "",
"cep": ""
},
  "Total de registros: 21"
],
```

**$cat**

```
{
"codigo": "36",
"nome": "Sub 10",
"ordem": "340"
},
  "Total de registros: 36"
],
```

Comment: O erro é bem claro, o 2º parametro que está a passar no `array_search` não é um array e deveria ser. Agora sem saber qual a linha que deu o erro, nem que valores tem os arrays de dados `$colunas`, `$loc` e `$cat` é dificil de responder.

Comment: as variáveis $colunas, $loc, $cat, pegam valores retornador em json, são muitos, vou adicionar os dois últimos de cada, e as linhas com erro, obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: @Isac editei a pergunta, é isso que precisamos?

Comment: creio que o erro se da devido a essa última linha dos retornos JSON  **&"Total de registros: 36"** por isso eu usei o  is_array como condição.

Comment: Tou na duvida se você colocou o json direto na variável e ela é um texto ou se tem de facto um array. `var_dump($categoria);` e `var_dump($cat);` dão o que ?

Comment: então, o que eu queria fazer era pegar dois valores, por exemplo, $colunas['codigo'], se ele for igual ao $result['mandante'], me trazer o nome da equipe, que fica em $colunas($equipe, 'nome');, essa função é somente pra substituir id por nome.

Comment: dei o var_dump no código, se quiser dar uma olhada está printada na home dessa url http://circuitoescolar.com.br/

Comment: negativaram minha pergunta, eu estou pesquisando a dois dias, mas não consegui resolver por ser realmente iniciante, eu só preciso de uma explicação...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você inverteu os parâmetros da função array_search: 
[PHP:array_search()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php)

Comment: no caso seria assim? $key5 = array_search($mod, $camp['modalidade']);

Comment: se eu inverto a ordem dos parâmetros, ele retorna o mesmo erro no segundo...

Comment: por acaso eu consigo comparar mais de uma variável dentro de um único is_array? por exemplo if(!is_array($camp, $result)){

Comment: não, mas você pode fazer duas verificações usando o operador lógico E (&&) if(!is_array($camp) && !is_array($result)){}

Comment: no array_search, o primeiro parâmetro é o valor que vc quer procurar, e o segundo parâmetro é o array

Comment: entendi, muito bom, obrigado pela ajuda!